# How to write angularJS directive correctly

Tags: javascript, angularjs, pug

I am a bit new to angular and I was typing up a directive an it does not work. I think it is because I did not write the directive correctly, but I can't seem to find the answer anywhere. am I allowed to use directive twice?

```
    'use strict';

    /* Directives */

    angular.module('myApp.directives', []).

      directive('appVersion', function (version) {
        return function(scope, elm, attrs) {
          elm.text(version);
        };

      directive('ngFocus', [function() {
      var FOCUS_CLASS = "ng-focused";
      return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ctrl) {
          ctrl.$focused = false;
          element.bind('focus', function(evt) {
            element.addClass(FOCUS_CLASS);
            scope.$apply(function() {ctrl.$focused = true;});
          }).bind('blur', function(evt) {
            element.removeClass(FOCUS_CLASS);
            scope.$apply(function() {ctrl.$focused = false;});
          });
        }
      }
    }]);

    });

EDIT: Here is my jade template ask asked for in the comments below

login
     form(name='signup_form', novalidate='novalidate', ng-submit='signupForm()')
      fieldset
        legend Signup

        .row
        .error(ng-show='signup_form.name.$dirty && signup_form.name.$invalid && !signup_form.name.$focused')

        label Your name

        input(ng-class='{error: signup_form.name.$dirty && signup_form.name.$invalid}', type='text', placeholder='Name', name='name', ng-model='signup.name', ng-minlength='3', ng-maxlength='20', required='required', ng-focus='ng-focus')

        .error(ng-show='signup_form.name.$dirty && signup_form.name.$invalid')
          small.error(ng-show='signup_form.name.$error.required')
            | Your name is required.
          small.error(ng-show='signup_form.name.$error.minlength')
            | Your name is required to be at least 3 characters
          small.error(ng-show='signup_form.name.$error.maxlength')
            | Your name cannot be longer than 20 characters

        br

        label Your email

        .error(ng-show='signup_form.email.$dirty && signup_form.email.$invalid && !signup_form.email.$focused')

        input(ng-class='{error: signup_form.email.$dirty && signup_form.name.$invalid}', type='text', placeholder='Email', name='email', ng-model='signup.email', ng-minlength='3', ng-maxlength='20', required='required', ng-focus='ng-focus')
        .error(ng-show='signup_form.email.$dirty && signup_form.email.$invalid')
          small.error(ng-show='signup_form.email.$error.required')
            | Your name is required.
          small.error(ng-show='signup_form.email.$error.minlength')
            | Your name is required to be at least 3 characters
          small.error(ng-show='signup_form.email.$error.maxlength')
            | Your name cannot be longer than 20 characters

        button.button.radius(type='submit') Submit
```

Comment: Can you post your html and css pls?

Comment: I used jade I will also post that

Answer (score 3):

The first thing I notice is a syntax error. You've got two directives sitting on top of one another. If you have multiple directives in a file, declare them like this:

```
angular.module('myApp.directives', []). 
 directive('directiveA', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'EA',
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {}
    }
  }).
  directive('directiveB', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'A',
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {}
    }
  }).
  directive('directiveC', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'E',
      link: function(scope, element, attrs) {}
    }
  });
```

Fix this and let us know if you still have issues.